# zsh shows PROMPT value on sudo su?

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

I have zshrc file as

```
PROMPT='%F{cyan}%.%f %F{red}>%f%F{yellow}>%f%F{green}>%f '
RPROMPT='%F{green}%*%f'
export PS1;
```

on command

> sudo su

**how do i remove the PROMPT value here ?**

```
~ >>> sudo su                                                          23:28:31
%F{cyan}%.%f %F{red}>%f%F{yellow}>%f%F{green}>%f
%F{cyan}%.%f %F{red}>%f%F{yellow}>%f%F{green}>%f exit                  
exit
~ >>>                                                                  23:29:02
```

[Terminal Screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGaXZ.png)

Comment: `sudo zsh`? It looks like the command is launching a different shell, maybe `sh` instead of `zsh` (nb: running  a shell as root can be hazardous, and usually isn't necessary).

Comment: Don't export `PS1`. Its value is shell-specific, and `su` is apparently *not* running `zsh`. (`zsh` automatically updates the value of `PS1`, the standard prompt variable, whenever you change the value of `PROMPT`.)